# Min-distance algorithm in R

Tags: c++, r, subsequence

I've written a function in C++ that does the following: given a (possibly very long) vector `x` and a threshold `thr`, find a subsequence `y` of `x` such that `x[1]∈y`, `x[length(x)]∈y`, and `∀i∈1:length(y)  y[i+1]-y[i]`≥`thr`.  The intention is to find a short subsequence of `x` where `plot(x)` "looks the same" as `plot(x[subsequence])`, in the sense that the resolution of the graph is `thr`.

The function is part of an R package, using the `Rcpp` interface to call C++ functions.  The source is here:  https://gist.github.com/kenahoo/8922376 . (It actually operates on a `data.frame`, not a simple vector, but it's equivalent to operating on each column independently as a vector and then merging the index sequences.)

I would like to find an equivalent pure-R solution that's nice & efficient - one obvious idea is something like `which(diff(x)>thr)`, but this is ***not*** appropriate, because it will miss any slow drifts in the values that build up over time to more than `thr`.

**Example:**

```
> set.seed(123)
> x <- cumsum(runif(100, -1, 1))
> y <- downsampleForPlot(data.frame(x=x), 2.5)
> y
[1]   1  11  26  46  57  71  81 100
```

That produces an approximation like this:

```
> plot(x)
> lines(stepfun(y[-1], x[y], f=0), col='blue')
```

[image: approximation plot]

Any ideas for this are welcome.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that `y` always starts with the first value of `x`?

Comment: A simple example with some data would be helpful

Comment: @BrodieG - correct, the first and last elements of `x` are always in `y`.  Actually the last element isn't really necessary, not sure why I put that in.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand, though I fear that a genuinely vectorized approach here will be somewhat inefficient because you need to recompute the differences each time you break the threshold, and that the vectorized approaches will have to compute the differences for the entire `x` vector each time.  You can get around this with `for` loops, but then you'll just have a slightly less efficient version of what you have in `Rcpp`.  Hopefully someone can come up with a clever "R Style" solution that doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Yeah, I had an implementation in pure R first, with `for` loops, but it was extremely slow, which is why I created the C++ version.  I've been trying to think of some built-in R function (e.g. `findInterval` for binary searches) that I could build from, but haven't come up with anything.